# Why doesn't the Linguistics Stack Exchange have a different icon?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange

The Phisics, Music, Science Fiction etc sites have different icons. Why doesn't this one have one too? And is there any prerequisite to a site that may prevent this one to have an icon?

Comment: Suppose prerequisite is having a good idea for a logo to begin with? I propose ripping the logo of a stuck out tongue from the Rolling Stones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linguistics SE was in beta until very recently. ([Congratulations to our 29 oldest beta sites - They're now no longer beta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta)) We are out of beta now, but only in name. We have none of the features of mature SE sites.

Going by the phases in [Design-Independent Graduation is on for early September!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) Linguistics SE has only gained the first bullet point of Phase 1. For all practical purposes, just assume we're still in beta here.